# Facebook account deleted but shows up on google?

Tags: facebook

Someone I know, Miss Green (this name is fabricated due to confidentiality), told me she deleted her facebook account because someone else got mad at her for not adding them as her facebook friend...

Miss Green has a name that is not shared by any public net user on this planet... because she's the last one that runs in her family with a particular surname... but after her "deletion" of her facebook her name still appears on google, one of the searches being "Miss Green Profiles - Facebook", and when I click on the link of this particular result, no profiles appear on that facebook page...

Now I'm wondering... why is Miss Green's facebook profile name still on google search but when I click into it nothing shows up?
Could it be that the profile is not actually deleted/ deactivated, but only set to private?

Your opinions and comments will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Google caches results even after deletion. Wait a while.

Answer (score 3):

I assume after some time the link will automatically be removed. If you want to remove it urgently, you might try Google's URL Removal page : https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

I hope this would help.